# Select first list in table - CSS first-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree. I'm have a table with 6 columns, each with an ordered list in. I want them all to have a border except for the first list.

[The site is in development here](http://www.digiflipconcepts.com/qcspares/) Basically though the html is

```
<tr>
 <td>
   <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
   </ol>
 </td>
 <td>
   <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
   </ol>
 </td>
 <td>
   <ol>
    <li>hello</li>
   </ol>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I thought the first-child of tr would work like so `tr:first-child ol {style}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`:first-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) selector is CSS2 and isn't supported on IE6. If IE6 is important then you'll need to give the first child a class you can select on instead. But the correct syntax is:

```
tr td:first-child ol { ... }
```

When you do:

```
tr:first-child ...
```

you're actually selecting `<tr>` elements that *are* first children. Also be aware that:

```
tr :first-child ...
```

is selecting the first children *of* table rows.

Comment: Excellent thanks very much, it is working now :)

I don't need to worry about IE6 for this site (thank heavens!), thanks again

Comment: Be careful with `tr :first-child` because this targets anything that is a first child within a `tr`. It might target any images, links, spans etc in your markup unexpectedly. You almost certainly mean: `tr td:first-child, tr th:first-child` when you write that.

Comment: @adamnfish: Or simply `tr > :first-child`, because in nested tables your selector would select all nested `td` and `th` which are first children as well...

Answer (score 3):

That's not quite how it works, `tr:first-child ol` selects the *tr* that is the first child of its parent element. You must use the `first-child` pseudoclass on the `td` instead.